# MemoryError during computation of dot product of huge sparse matrices

Tags: python, matrix, scipy, sparse-matrix, matrix-multiplication

Assume the following case: I got an adjacency matrix of a two mode network where one dimension represents some items (posts) and the other tags that occur under each item. Now I want to fold that two mode network in order to get a one mode network of item-to-item relations where the value of each link represents the number of shared tags of both items. That can be reached by a simple matrix multiplication as the following:

[image]

or in code:

```py
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix, save_npz, load_npz

# load matrix
tpm = csr_matrix(load_npz('tag_post_matrix.npz'))

# compute dot product
cn = tpm.transpose().dot(tpm)

# save result
save_npz('content_network_abs.npz', cn)
```

which raises this error after running for a while:

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-10ff98c2505a> in <module>()
----> 1 cn = tpm.transpose().dot(tpm)
      2 save_npz(expand('content_network_abs.npz'), cn)
      3 

/opt/anaconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/base.py in dot(self, other)
    359 
    360         """
--> 361         return self * other
    362 
    363     def power(self, n, dtype=None):

/opt/anaconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/base.py in __mul__(self, other)
    477             if self.shape[1] != other.shape[0]:
    478                 raise ValueError('dimension mismatch')
--> 479             return self._mul_sparse_matrix(other)
    480 
    481         # If it's a list or whatever, treat it like a matrix

/opt/anaconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/compressed.py in _mul_sparse_matrix(self, other)
    500                                     maxval=nnz)
    501         indptr = np.asarray(indptr, dtype=idx_dtype)
--> 502         indices = np.empty(nnz, dtype=idx_dtype)
    503         data = np.empty(nnz, dtype=upcast(self.dtype, other.dtype))
    504 

MemoryError:
```

I monitored RAM during execution without any extraordinary observations (I have plenty of memory: ~1TB).

The inital matrix has ~24000000 non zero entries (very sparse) and I would expect the resulting matrix to be quite sparse too.

Do I have a general misunderstanding of the topic or is there a bug somewhere in the code?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is your system and/or Python 32-bit or 64-bit?

Comment: The calculation is done in 2 steps.  One identifies the size of result.  With that information it initializes the attribute arrays and then fills them.  `nnz` is the number of nonzero terms that the result will contain.  `inidices` is the array that holds column indices, one per nonzero term.

Comment: What's the sparsity of `tpm`?  Do you expect the sparsity of the result to be higher or lower?

Comment: @PhilipTzou I'm running a 64-Bit version of Python 3.7 on Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: @hpaulj I expect sparsity of the result matrix to be lower

Comment: The result will be (nxn), larger than `tpm`.  When I test smaller random matricies I get an increased density, I get a 3x increase in sparsity.  If sparsity isn't low enough I can end up with a nearly dense one.

Comment: With a random matrix of that size and sparsity, my session dies.

Answer (score -1):

Try to increase virtual memory. 1.5x extra VM worked better for me.

Comment: The OP mentions 1TB of RAM.  There is no indication that this is a virtual machine.  So adjusting the VM size may not be possible.

Comment: I wasn't talking about a virtual machine. 1TB is physical RAM. Adjust windows or mac virtual memory should help.